# How to prove $\sum^{m}_{k=0}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}=0$ for $m=1,3,5,\dots,2n-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I would like to prove that
$$
\sum^{m}_{k=0}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}=0,\quad m=1,3,5,\cdots,2n-1,n\in\mathbb{N}^*.
$$
Currently I have no idea of this: expanding $\displaystyle\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}$ yields $\dfrac{(2n-k)!m!}{n!(n-k)!(m-k)!k!}$, which does not simplify to anything. I tried also considering $P_n(x):=\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{2n-k}{n}x^k$, then $\displaystyle\sum^{m}_{k=0}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}$ is the $x^m$-coefficient of $(1+x)^mP_n(-2x)$, which does not seem to help because I can't simplify $P_n(x)$. I don't know how $m$ being odd plays a role either. Could anybody please help me with this identity? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your expansion of $\displaystyle\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}$ (as it is written now) is incorrect. It should be $\dfrac{(2n-k)!m!}{n!(n-k)!(m-k)!k!}$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Yes, silly me! I corrected it.

Comment: Rewriting as $$\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k}\binom{2n-k}{n}2^k=0$$ might suggest an inclusion-exclusion proof.  Count $n$-subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ that avoid $m$ properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try the Snake Oil Method with $m=2l-1$ for a positive integer $l$.
Before we start, let us recall a few well-known functions and relevant identities involving those. Let
$$
B(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^n, \quad C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}x^n.
$$
Then
$$
B(x)=\frac{1}{1-2xC(x)} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n-k}{n}x^n=x^kB(x)C(x)^k.
$$
Now we can proceed.
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}x^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}x^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n-k}{n}x^n\right)\binom{m}{k}(-2)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\left(x^kB(x)C(x)^k\right)\binom{m}{k}(-2)^k\\
&=B(x)\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\left(-2xC(x)\right)^k\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2xC(x)}\left(1-2xC(x)\right)^m\\
&=\left(1-2xC(x)\right)^{m-1}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{B(x)}\right)^{2l-2}=\left(\frac{1}{B(x)^2}\right)^{l-1}=(1-4x)^{l-1}.
\end{split}
$$
In our problem, we want $1\le l\le n$, i.e. $0\le l-1<n$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k}=[x^n](1-4x)^{l-1}=0.
$$
In fact, more generally, for $m=2l+1$, where $l$ is a nonnegative integer, we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2l+1}(-2)^k\binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{2l+1}{k}=(-4)^n\binom{l}{n}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\binom{2n-k}{n} = [x^n](1+x)^{2n-k}$, hence

$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^m (-2)^k \binom{2n-k}{n}\binom{m}{k} &= [x^n] (1+x)^{2n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^m (-2)^k (1+x)^{-k} \binom{m}{k} \\
&= [x^n] (1+x)^{2n} \left(1-\frac{2}{1+x}\right)^m \\
&= [x^n](x+1)^{2n-m} (x-1)^m.
\end{align}$$
Let $f(x) = (x+1)^{2n-m}(x-1)^m$, we can notice that $[x^{k}]f(x) = (-1)^m [x^{2n-k}] f(x)$, as follows from the fact that $x^{2n} f(x^{-1}) = (-1)^m f(x)$. But for $k=n$ and odd $m$ it means that $[x^n] f(x) = -[x^n]f(x)$, which can only be true if $[x^n] f(x) = 0$, QED.

Comment: That's very elegant, thanks! I have to apologize and regret for not being able to accept because the other answer was faster :)